# Increase the size of the tableView's cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, label, tableview

I have a tableView with a custom cell which consists of 3 labels, name, book and chapter. Unfortunately it seems like my cell is not big enough for the 3 labels and I want to make it bigger. What should I do in my code below to achieve this in the best way? /Regards

Picture of the cell's in the tableView: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vrzpu9&s=6

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BookmarkCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
Bookmark *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *chunks = [item.name componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

NSString *name;
NSString *book;
NSString *chapter;

if ([chunks count] > 0)
{
    name = [chunks objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([chunks count] > 1)
    {
        book = [chunks objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([chunks count] > 2)
        {
            chapter = [chunks objectAtIndex:2];
        }
    }
}

UIView * pNewContentView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
CGRect labelFrame= pNewContentView.bounds;
labelFrame.size.height= labelFrame.size.height * 0.25;

UILabel* pLabel1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel1];

labelFrame.origin.y= labelFrame.size.height;
UILabel* pLabel2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel2];

labelFrame.origin.y= labelFrame.origin.y + labelFrame.size.height;
UILabel* pLabel3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel3];

[cell.contentView addSubview:pNewContentView];

[pLabel1 setText:(name)];    
[pLabel2 setText:(book)];  
[pLabel3 setText:(chapter)];       


//cell.textLabel.text = chapter;
//cell.textLabel.text = name;
//cell.detailTextLabel.text = book;


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its easy to customize the height of a UITableViewCell

just add the delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    return 70; // or whatever height you need
}
```